# Get the list of property of Object from List of Object dynamically in java

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

I am trying to get a list of property ,means I have a class User and it has a property name and I have a public method getName() to get the name of user, Now my problem is I want to create a method which takes a generic list , and method name , And with helping of stream API I get the list of property of class.

Means if I pass the list of user and method name 'getName' in test method then it returns the list of username.

```
public static boolean test(List<?> propertyList) throws Exception{
                Class<?> c = Class.forName(propertyList.get(0).getClass().getCanonicalName());
                Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);

             !propertyList.stream().map(c::method).allMatch(new HashSet<>()::add);
        }
```

Comment: where do you define ``methodName``?

Comment: Hi f1sh , actually here  methodName is  getter method name of property like i mention in description,                                                                                         e.g;   List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
  users.add(new User("f1sh"));
  users.add(new User("Bhushan"));
  
now i call my test method and pass list of user and method name            test(users, "getName")

Comment: `Class.forName(propertyList.get(0).getClass().getCanonicalName());` makes no sense. `getClass()` already returns a `Class` object. 

 In the best case `x == Class.forName(x.getCanonicalName());`, but if not, you were better off using `x` instead of `Class.forName(x.getCanonicalName())`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t put together a `Class` object and a `Method` object using `::` like you do with `c::method`. You can express the dynamic invocation using `method::invoke`, but unfortunately, that’ll be incompatible with the expected type `Function`, because `Method.invoke` can throw checked exceptions.

So you can use a lambda expression encapsulating the dynamic invocation and catching the reflective exceptions:

```
public static boolean test(List<?> propertyList, String methodName) throws Exception{
    Method method = propertyList.get(0).getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName);

    return !propertyList.stream().map(x -> {
        try {
            return method.invoke(x);
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("invoking "+method, ex);
        }
    }).allMatch(new HashSet<>()::add);
}
```

If using a `Method` as `Function` is a recurring problem in your code, you can create a factory method utilizing Java’s built-in features for dynamic class creation:

```
public static boolean test(List<?> propertyList, String methodName) throws Exception {
    Method method = propertyList.get(0).getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
    return !propertyList.stream().map(toFunction(method)).allMatch(new HashSet<>()::add);
}
public static Function toFunction(Method m) throws IllegalAccessException {
    return MethodHandleProxies.asInterfaceInstance(Function.class,
        MethodHandles.lookup().unreflect(m));
}
```

But note that there are some conceptional flaws in your method. It relies on the `List` not being empty and imposes unintended constraints on the type of the first list element. A list may contain elements of different actual types having a common base type as declared element type. Even if all elements have the same type, `getDeclaredMethod` will only search the most specific class and ignore inherited methods.

In other words, even using `"toString"` as method name can fail as the procedure does not look for `Object.toString`, so it may fail to find the method or it may find a method in the first element’s type which is too specific for the other elements of the list.

A better design would be to let the caller provide a type:

```
public static <T> boolean test(
    List<? extends T> propertyList, Class<T> type, String methodName) throws Exception {

    Method method = type.getMethod(methodName);
    return !propertyList.stream().map(toFunction(method)).allMatch(new HashSet<>()::add);
}
```

This allows to pass in list having a declared element type being more specific than the type of class to search the method and also having particular elements of a more specific type than the declare element type and even supports empty lists.

Note that `getMethod`’s search will consider inherited methods but only look for `public` methods.